# can compiler reorganize instructions over sleep call?

Tags: c++, compiler-optimization

Is there a difference if it is the first use of the variable or not. For example are a and b treated differently?

```
void f(bool&a, bool& b)
{
    ...
    a=false;
    boost::this_thread::sleep...//1 sec sleep
    a=true;
    b=true;
    ...
}
```

EDIT: people asked why I want to know this.
1. I would like to have some way to tell the compiler not to optimize(swap the order of the execution of the instructions) in some function, and using atomic and or mutexes is much more complicated than using sleep(and in my case sleeping is not a performance problem). 
2. Like I said this is generally important to know.

Comment: It sounds as if there's a specific reason you want to know this. If there is, please let us know -- this will usually help people give you a better answer.

Comment: In general, I want to know if I'm certain that loading of something will take less than 100 ms and if i decide to not use locks, but to wait 1 second to publish that it is loaded. I know that this is a bad practice, but I really need to avoid mutexes. :)

Comment: Never make assumptions about how long operations take. What if your application is in full action, and then, upon full-moon, an evil instance of outlook pops up because some naughty soul kicked you a friendly email, then blocks for a few seconds the CPU core your app runs on, and you get out of sync? Always think about it like this: The unprobable, evil stuff virtually never appears to you, but rather right in the face of your favourite customer (I think Scott Meyers said something similar to this)

Comment: Use the mutexes and/or atomics. They express your intent to the people reading your code. Putting in a call to a random function in the middle does not, even if you make sure that call cannot somehow be optimized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can't really tell. On scenario could be that the compiler has full introspection to your function at the calling site (and possibly does inline it), in which case it can jumble your function with the caller, and then do optimizations appropriately.

It could then e.g. completely optimize away a and b because there is no code that depends on a and b. Or it might see that you violate aliasing rules so that a and b refer to the same entity, and then merge them according to your program flow.

But it could also be that you tell the compiler to not optimize at all, e.g. with g++'s -O0 flag, in which case not much will happen.

The only proof for your particular platform <sup>*</sup>, can be made by looking at the generated assembly, or by telling the compiler to please output some log about what it optimizes (g++ has many flags for that).

---

<sup>*</sup> *compiler+flags used to compile compiler+version+add-ons, hardware, operating system; even the weather might be relevant if your compiler omits some optimizations if it takes to long [which would actually be cool feature for debug builds, imho]*

Comment: Sure you can tell. There is a code that depends on a and b--the function calling `f` that was not written yet, but which the compiler has to cater for. It can't assume that the called function does not have reference to a and b either, because it's a library function it does not see. Linker possibly could (if it wasn't using shared libraries, which it usually will) and could rearrange the operations, but knows better than to do so across a system call (because otherwise half of threaded programs out there would stop working).

Comment: @Jan Hudec: No, you cannot. You can maybe for the specific case of a function with external linkage (but we can't tell linkage from provided example), but this doesn't exclude the case where this functions is called _internally_. And then, it depends on a dependency analysis upon a and b.

Comment: Downvoter: Care to explain? We can prolly learn from each other today.

Answer (score 0):

They are not local (because they are references), so it **can't**, because it can't tell whether the called function sees them or not and has to assume that it does. If they were local variables, it could, because local variables are not visible to the called function unless pointer or reference to them was created.

Comment: How can you tell it can't without knowing the rest of the code plus the build flags plus the compiler? edit: Ah yes, I see you are the optimization pro from that other question ...

Comment: @phresnel: Assuming `boost::this_thread::sleep` is not fully inlineable (which it is not; calls standard C library function which is not) and assuming this function is non-static (we see the function signature in the question, so we can make that assumption), we know for sure that the compiler neither knows what the caller of `f` does (it may not be even written yet) nor what the sleep does (at least part of it lives in a library, which is separate object), it has no way to ensure the order of operations does not matter, therefore must assume it does.

Comment: Being fully inlined does not imply that it is recursively inlined. Also, when the compiler compiles the caller, it might see more than by just looking at presented code. Of course, when the presented function has external <strike>linkage</strike> visibility, the compiler must burn it into the object-file, and we also have a situation as you assume, but it doesn't necessarily imply relevance; the relevance really is at the caller site, and how much the compiler sees *there*, and a blanket `can't` in boldface is simply wrong.